# What is mean by Properties in java?

Tags: java, properties

According the notes i referred

> Properties in java means, its a configuration file which holds the key
>   and value in pair. Eg. System Properties.

I understood about the System properties well. And am clear about how to load and store the properties file.

My question is,

if suppose we want to store any properties details for our application, what we will be it is.?
what for it is mainly used.?
what does configuration exactly mean in java application other than System configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties files contain "Key-Value" pairs of variables used in your project.

Suppose there are Some Environment variables or configurations you want to set before execution of your program.

Another example suppose in your program there are some conditions which are decided by the user before executing the Program.

Property files are just another way to provide Input.

**For example**:

**Scenario** : Lets consider if Condition-A is true then code-A must be executed else code -B.

**PropertyFile** - condition.properties

```
#true/flase as per requirement
Condition_A=true
```

**Java Code** :

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("condition.properties");

// load a properties file
prop.load(input);

// get the property value and print it out
String value = prop.getProperty("database");

//Condition
if("true".equals(value))
   //Code-A
else
   //Code-B
```

Also It can be used to save some properties by your program which can be read later on :

```
Properties applicationProps = new Properties();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("appProperties");
applicationProps.store(out, "value");
out.close();
```

Further reading - [java-properties-file-examples](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) , [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

Properties are key value pairs that can be used for any purpose in java. Wherever you need to use key value pairs, such as database configuration data, language codes, etc.

Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html as it is explained clearly there.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Properties files contain "Key-Value" pairs of variables usd in your project. example : target=android-9 for an android project. It can
>      also contain other variables not necessary in the "actual code" but
>      for building the project (like libraries referenced.. )

Answer (score 0):

A widely used configuration is the one that you mentioned, where you have pairs of Key, Value defined in a file. You can have your own configurations defined as you wish. But you must make sure that the class that parses the file knows how your data is stored, so I think is better to have a format that is easy to define/update.

Answer (score 0):

Just take an example that you want to configure the database and for which you want the information like db url, dbname, password, username. One method is to hard code it in your code and second is to store these values in property file

```
url=--
username=---
pass=---
dbname=---
```

now you can use this property file in any program by loading it and future modification in db can reflect very easily by this.